# Failing to create couchbase-type buckets via Couchbase 4.1 API ... what is going wrong?

Tags: couchbase

I'm using the following to create a couchbase-style bucket against couchbase 4.1:

```
$ curl -X POST -v -u admin:fakepwd \
-d 'name=mybucket' -d 'ramQuotaMB=256' -d 'bucketType=couchbase' \
-d 'replicaNumber=0' -d 'replicaIndex=0' -d 'proxyPort=0' \
-d 'authType=sasl' -d 'saslPassword=changeit' \
'http://localhost:8091/pools/default/buckets'
```

However, when I query the bucket, like so:

```
$  curl -u admin:fakepwd http://localhost:8091/pools/default/buckets/mybucket
{"name":"mybucket","bucketType":"membase","authType":"sasl","saslPassword":"fakepwd","proxyPort":0,"replicaIndex":false,...}
```

It tells me it's a membase bucket.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have actually successfully created a couchbase bucket!

To understand why the bucketType is `membase` instead of `couchbase` you have to first learn about the history of Couchbase as a company.

As explained on the [Couchbase Inc wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Couchbase,_Inc.#History), Couchbase was formed as a merger of `membase` and `couchone`, retaining much of the legacy code from the `membase` days.

As a result of this there are many references to Couchbase's previous incarnations as they are deeply intrenched into the current codebase, including `couchbase` buckets being still known as `membase` buckets internally. `Memcached` buckets will be displayed as `memcached` buckets when hitting the appropriate endpoints in the REST API. These references are retained for backwards-compatibility purposes (especially in the case of upgrades) where there is little benefit in updating them.

Another prime example of this legacy naming is the cluster manager process, `ns_server` which is named after another previous incarnation of the company [Northscale](http://www.couchbase.com/press-releases/northscale-announces-funding-new-ceo)(ns is short for northscale).